# GTsummary PIndent Third Time Issue

Tags: r, indentation, gtsummary

I need help indenting a third time using gtsummary. Ideally, 'Documented Virus' would be indented underneath 'Bronchiolitis/pneumonitis', and everything underneath that is already indented would be indented one more over.  The issue is I can't get '  Hours Pre-arrest: +COVID-19' to indent over a third time.  I tried to add some space in front of the labels so it would appear indented, but somewhere is trimming white space, potentially the element themes, but I can't figure out where.  Any ideas on how to indent a third time? Short snippet of code below.

[current table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWNNr.png)

Comment: can you share code and data instead of a picture of the table

Comment: also see this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76723819/how-can-i-indent-specified-rows-when-using-tbl-summary-from-the-gtsummary-packag